# copying the entire contents of a directory recursively using clojure

Tags: clojure

I wish to emulate `cp -R` using clojure. Is there an idiomatic way of writing this function so that the entire contents of a directory is recursively copied?

Comment: Yes, it's a recursive traversal of a tree. Whenever you find a file you open the same file name in the destination for write, read from the source and write to the destination. It's the same as in any other language, except using java.io under the hood. Why do you want/need to do this in Clojure? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Are you ok with java? This dependency is only a few hundred KB: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyDirectory%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File%29

Answer (score 1):

(given there's still interest in this answer):

One can use java `java.io.File` with clojure's `file-seq`:

```clj
(require '[clojure.java.io :as io])

(->> "/path"
     (io/file)
     (file-seq)
     (run! (your-fn-that-copies-files-and-creates-folders)))
```

`file-seq` will return a [tree-like structure](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/file-seq) for your files/folders.

In order to keep a consistent directory structure from your root point onwards, we must take an absolute path and turn it into a relative path:

```clj
(require '[clojure.string :as str]
         '[clojure.data :as data])

(defn- path->chunks [file] (str/split (.getAbsolutePath file) #"/"))
(defn  path->relative [root file]
    (str/join "/" (filter some? (second (data/diff (path->chunks root)
                                                   (path->chunks file))))))
```

You can combine all that to perform your recursive copy.